# Best options for building a web app with SimpleDB as a data source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I have seen PHP libraries for SimpleDB but nothing too interesting... are there any best practices or frameworks for this or should I just go at it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from Amazon's basic PHP library for SimpleDB, there are two others that I know of.

[Paws](http://code.google.com/p/paws-library/) is a SimpleDB specific library, and

[Tarzan](http://tarzan-aws.com/) which has support for many Amazon web services and seems to be well documented.

One thing to be aware of is that any individual SimpleDB request may not be as fast as a normal database call, but much of the time you can make your calls in parallel.

If you are able to run your web app on Amazon EC2 (either self hosted or if you can find a hosting company that uses EC2) you will see a much lower latency in SimpleDB requests than you'll get from a PHP host outside of Amazon's cloud. When running on EC2 I typically get round-trip latencies of 2-7ms to SimpleDB (not including the requst processing time).